# ActionSheet pushViewController Problems

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiactionsheet

I am having problems presenting a view controller from an action sheet in iOS 7. My program just seems to skip over:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:viewController animated:TRUE];
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if `self.navigationController` is `nil`?

Comment: Yes, and it is nil when there are tabs, and not nil when there are not tabs. Could this have to do with the tabBarController?

Answer (score 1):

`self.navigationController` is `nil` if the view controller is not embedded inside a navigation controller.  Sending a message to `nil` is ignored (which is why your program is skipping over that line).

Change `self.navigationController` to `self`, or `self.tabBarController` if you're using a tab bar controller, or `self.splitViewController` if you're using a split view controller.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try present new view controller in `- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`